# Doubts with Object declaration and accessing properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

If I send an object like this:

```
this.someProvider.someFunction({data: myData});
```

I need to access it with:

```
someFunction(something: Object) {
    console.log(something['data']);  // myData
    console.log(something.data)      // 'Property data does not exist on type Object'
}
```

But if I declare the object:

```
var object = {};
object['data'] = myData;

this.someProvider.someFunction(object);
```

I can access it like:

```
someFunction(something: Object) {
    console.log(something.data)      // myData
    console.log(something['data']);  // myData
}
```

Why? What is the difference between these two ways of declaring and accessing the properties of an object?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You need to show us how you get to `this`

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:typescript]; are you actually using TS? By *"It doesn't works"* do you mean the compiler tells you `something` doesn't have a `data` property?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the property accessor should work, despite of the style.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm using typescript and the compiler says to me: 'Property data does not exist on type Object'.

Comment: In fact, the question is: what is the difference between these two ways of declaring and accessing the properties of an object

Comment: So if you're using TS, *add types*. Turn on the *"no implicit any"* option.

Comment: I'm using Object type in the function declaration, but I did forgot that in the question

Comment: Anything else you forgot? Please double-check your examples, as presented, and ensure you actually get the outputs you're claiming. `Object` isn't a particularly useful type, you might as well not be using TS if you're not going to give yourself and the compiler a little more help than that.

Comment: It's ionic 2, and it uses typescript. The reason of using Object, is because i saw that in many tutorials, i dont know. Dont hit me.

Comment: @D.Simon  Thank's Simon. It's correct, and that's all I asked.